# Looping through multiple tables which vary in length

Tags: excel, vba, loops, charts, shapes

I have the following table:
[image]

And a macro that loops through the first section of the table (rows 6-7) in order to create the Pie-Charts on the right. My target now is to loop through all other tables automatically as well. The next one would be in row11 and create a new Pie Chart for that row, then the next table (rows 15-16) and so on. The header of each table is always red. The problem is that the length of the tables vary, meaning for example in the table1 ("Build", A5:K7) there can be 2 rows like here or 50, but each time I need one PieChart for each row.

Currently I have the following working code for Table1 ("Build" A6:K79) to create the 2 PieCharts automatically, but Im unsure how to make one loop for all tables on the sheet.

```
Dim rownumber As Integer
Dim LabelRange As Range
Dim ValueRange As Range
Dim Chart As ChartObject
Dim LeftIndent As Long
Dim TopIndent As Long
Dim InhaltsRangeString As String
Dim LetzteZeile As Long

'Intialpositionen für Graphen
LeftIndent = 726
TopIndent = 60
rownumber = 6 'Anfang der Buildtabelle in Reihe 6 (Spalte 1)


Set LabelRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testplan Überblick").Range("C5, E5, G5, I5")
Set TPsheet = Worksheets("Testplan Überblick")
Set ValueRange = Union(TPsheet.Cells(rownumber, 3), TPsheet.Cells(rownumber, 5), TPsheet.Cells(rownumber, 7), TPsheet.Cells(rownumber, 9))


'Loop through table 1 which always starts at row 6 (unlike the others which have no set starting point cause the ones before can vary in length!)

For rownumber = 6 To LetzteZeileFunktion Step 1 '"LetzteZeileFunktion" gives me the long value of the last row filled in table 1 

Set Chart = Sheets("Testplan Überblick").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=180, Width:=270, Top:=7, Height:=210)

With Chart
.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ValueRange
.Chart.ChartType = xlPie
.Chart.HasTitle = True
.Chart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = Sheets("Testplan Überblick").Cells(rownumber, 1).Value
.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = LabelRange
.Left = LeftIndent
.Top = TopIndent
.Name = Sheets("Testplan Überblick").Cells(rownumber, 1).Value
End With

TopIndent = TopIndent + 225
Next rownumber

End Sub
```

Any ideas on how to loop through all the tables even though they can all differ in length (amount of rows filled with content for charts) would be greatly appreciated!
Cheers

Comment: You can just loop through the collection of `ListObjects` - you will find many examples around. Have you tried it and hit a problem?

Comment: Ah, ok these are not proper tables - is that the problem?

Comment: No they are not proper tables, all just normal data on one sheet but Im just unsure how to loop through it and only make the ones I want (not the read "table"-headings) into charts... I thought maybe loop through all until 2 consecutive empty rows are founds, then go 2 cells down from there and that should always bring me to the first content-row of a new table...

Comment: If the first row is always red, you could use `Find` and `FindFormat`. Better still, convert them to proper tables.

Comment: Look at using `.end(xlDown)` to find the first cell in table and then `.CurrentRegion.Address'

Comment: Or loop through `Areas` - only snag being that your first table appears to be adjacent to the text at the top.

Comment: I think I got the solution but unsure how to code it, maybe someone can help as its not a lot:
 `For rownumber = 6 To LastRow Step 1` 
-- if row with rownumber = empty, rownumber +3 (go 3 rows down and go on with loop) --

Comment: But not very robust. `if cells(rownumber,1).value="" then` ?

Comment: Implemented, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the text in one of the headers to identify the start of the data rows and a blank in column A to end. I have used "testfall qty" in column B.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateCharts()

    Const DATA = "Testplan Überblick"
    Const ROW_START = 5
    Const POSN_LEFT = 726
    Const POSN_TOP = 60
    Const COL = "B"
    Const HEADER = "testfall qty"

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngLabel As Range, rngValue As Range
    Dim iRow As Long, iLastRow As Long, count As Integer
    Dim oCht As ChartObject, sColA As String, bflag As Boolean
    bflag = False

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(DATA)
    ' scan down the sheet
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For iRow = ROW_START To iLastRow
        ' look for Testfall Qty as header
        sColA = ws.Cells(iRow, 1)
        If LCase(ws.Cells(iRow, COL)) = HEADER Then
           
            'set ranges
            Set rngLabel = ws.Range("C1, E1, G1, I1").Offset(iRow - 1)
            bflag = True

        ElseIf Len(sColA) > 0 And bflag Then
            ' create chart
            Set rngValue = ws.Range("C1, E1, G1, I1").Offset(iRow - 1)
            
            Set oCht = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=180, _
                      Width:=270, Top:=7, Height:=210)
            With oCht
                .Left = POSN_LEFT
                .Top = POSN_TOP + (count * 255)
                .Name = sColA
                With .Chart
                    .SetSourceData Source:=rngValue
                    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = rngLabel
                    .ChartType = xlPie
                    .HasTitle = True
                    .SetElement msoElementChartTitleAboveChart
                    .ChartTitle.Text = sColA
                End With
            End With
            count = count + 1
        Else
            ' end of chart data
            bflag = False
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox count & " Charts created", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Sadly cant give you +1 because I lack the reputation